# Finding `-moz-image-rect` in webkit?

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

When working with `-moz-image-rect` and backgrounds, I am able to use one image to change them all:

```
kings{
  background: -moz-image-rect(url('ring.jpg'), 3, 30, 30, 3) repeat-y;
}
lords{
  background:-moz-image-rect(url('ring.jpg'), 7, 70, 70, 7) repeat-x;
}    
men{
  background:-moz-image-rect(url('ring.jpg'), 9, 99, 90, 9) no-repeat;
}
```

So, this one `ring.jpg` is bound to all the div backgrounds.

This works very nicely in Firefox, but no such function seems to exist for webkit browers. 
  Is there any cross-browser option? Or at least something that works on webkit?

I am trying to limit the shown area of the image while still allowing the background to repeat.

Comment: nope, nothing like that exists for Webkit (as a matter of fact, for nothing but firefox)

Comment: @MightyPork Is it possible to do without using `-moz-image-rect()`?

Comment: Or must I wait until w3 comes out with their image fragments syntax?

Comment: I tried to google something relevant, but didn't find anything other than this firefox-only property..